# Error evaluating code , PHP , xdebug , API

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I've got this error when trying to evaluate an API function returning balance using remote development in phpstorm. In local I don't get this error:

[image: error message]

[image: php settings from remote]

[image: php settings from local]

I expect not get this error message when debugging.

Comment: I apologize for the disorder in the image descriptions.

Comment: the code stop debugging  here `$ch = curl_init($this->api_url);`

Comment: Don't post error messages, code or data as images. Post the actual text so that it can be indexed and searched. See [ask]

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thank you for the comment. I didn't know that errors are also indexed. It's good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I had to install cURL library: `sudo apt install php-cli` and it works :p